# python bottle deciding on return mimetype

Tags: python, format, return, bottle

I am using bottle for a POC restful service project. would someone kindly let me know what is the best way to decide if the caller wants me to send the response in JSON, XML, or HTML? I have seen some examples of this using request.mimetypes.best_match, but that needs me to import flask. is there a way to do this in bottle itself?
Thanks a lot,
Reza

Comment: Just curious, what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

The `Request` Mime-type(or content-type) is the type of the content being sent to the server - it does not mean this is the same type that should be returned by the server.

The client should know what the server `Response` type is going to be, and not otherwise - the server should not "guess" what response the client wants.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding query args that clients can use to tell you which response format they'd like.

For example, if your request currently looks like this:

```
http://myservice.com/get-item/id/190134
```

then modify it to one of these:

```
http://myservice.com/get-item/id/190134?response_format=json
http://myservice.com/get-item/id/190134?response_format=xml
http://myservice.com/get-item/id/190134?response_format=html
```

In your server code, `bottle.request.params.get('response_format', 'json')` will give you the desired response format (assuming 'json' is the default here).

P.S., Be sure to code defensively for unexpected values of 'response_format', and remember to set `bottle.response.content_type` accordingly.